# How to change urlencode spaces inside a sed capture group only?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have some markdown files with links like this one:

`[Royal Enfield Flying Flea](RE Flying Flea)`

And I'm trying to urlencode the second part of the link to become

`[Royal Enfield Flying Flea](RE%20Flying%20Flea)`

I'm using sed, which i think is the one tool best suited for the job. I already made some other transformations in the file using it. But I can use another, like awk if someone thinks it's better.

I also managed to capture the strings using `sed -E 's/\[([A-Za-z0-9 ]*)\]\(([A-Za-z0-9 ]*)\)/\1\2/'` but I couldn't found a ways to make substitution in the selected part. Only to show it as it is.

If someone can point me in the right path, I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl and a proper module to percent escape URL:

```
perl -MURI::Escape -pe 's/(\[.*?\])\((.*?)\)/"$1(" . uri_escape($2) . ")"/e' file
```

Yields:

```
[Royal Enfield Flying Flea](RE%20Flying%20Flea)
```

---

If you'd like to edit the file *in place*, use `-i` option:

```
perl -i -pe ......
```

---

The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\[` | [ |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `\]` | ] |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `\(` | ( |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |
| `\)` | ) |

---

See [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape)

Comment: Almost perfect solutions. But I was seeking for a sed only solution. 
Thanks anyway. I will use perl on my next project.

Comment: Most *Unix have both `sed` & `perl`. That's shell, you are not limited to use just one tool but awk, sed, ed, tr, paste, cut; perl, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
sed -E ':a;s/(\[[^][]*]\([^()[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]([^()]*\))/\1%20\2/;ta' file
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/casOvC):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='[Royal Enfield Flying Flea](RE Flying Flea)
[Some string here](another string there)'
sed -E ':a;s/(\[[^][]*]\([^()[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]([^()]*\))/\1%20\2/;ta' <<< "$s"
# => 
#    [Royal Enfield Flying Flea](RE%20Flying%20Flea)
#    [Some string here](another%20string%20there)
```

*Details*:

- `:a` - an `a` label
- `s` - `s`ubstitute action
- `(\[[^][]*]\([^()[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]([^()]*\))` - search pattern:

  - `(\[[^][]*]\([^()[:space:]]*)` - Group 1: a `[`, any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, then a `](` string, then any zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and whitespace
  - `[[:space:]]` - a whitespace
  - `([^()]*\))` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a literal `)`
- `\1%20\2` - replaces the match with Group 1 + `%20` + Group 2
- `ta` - upon a successful replacement, jumps back to the `a` label position.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/(\([^)]*) /\1%20/;ta' input_file
[Royal Enfield Flying Flea](RE%20Flying%20Flea)
```